# Rendering React component returns This expression is not callable. Type 'void' has no call signatures

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering a simple React component using Typescript. The problem is that when I render it in the `ReactDOM.redner` method I get the following error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'void' has no call signatures.
```

And I am not sure why, how can I fix it and render my component? Here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SplitButton from '../../../src/ListButton/SplitButton'

const App = () => {
    const items: any = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'];

    return (
      <div>
        <SplitButton items={items} text="Enabled Button" /> &nbsp;
        <SplitButton disabled={true} items={items} text="Disabled Button" />
      </div>
      );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
      document.querySelector('my-app')
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use install react package, then require. for example

```
npm install react-split-button --save
```

then you can use SplitButton component.
import SplitButton from ....

```
var SplitButton = require('react-split-button')
 
var items = [
    {
        label: 'save as',
        onClick: function(){
            console.log('saved as')
        },
        items: [
            {
                label: 'PDF',
                onClick: function(){
                    console.log('save as PDF')
                }
            },
            {
                label: 'Postscript'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'export',
        onClick: function(){
            console.log('exported')
        }
    },
]
 
function save(){
    console.log('SAVED!')
}
 
<SplitButton items={items} onClick={save}>
    Save
</SplitButton>
 
function onMenuClick(event, itemProps){
    console.log('You clicked ', itemProps.data.label)
}
 
<SplitButton items={items} onMenuClick={onMenuClick} onClick={save}>
    Save
</SplitButton>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Kendo React.
The *SplitButton* component is a named export from *@progress/kendo-react-buttons*, so you need to rework the import line as follows.

I also removed the *any* type annotation where *items* are declared, as it is not useful and actually in such case it is safer to let TypeScript guess that the items are a collection of strings.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { SplitButton } from '@progress/kendo-react-buttons';

const App = () => {
    const items = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'];

    return (
      <div>
        <SplitButton items={items} text="Enabled Button" /> &nbsp;
        <SplitButton disabled={true} items={items} text="Disabled Button" />
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.querySelector('my-app')
)
```

**[See DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j1scou?file=app/main.jsx)**